# How to get ALAsset from saved photo

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, alassetslibrary, alasset

Is there a way to know the ALAsset corresponding to an UIImage?

I use UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum for saving a photo and I need to identify it in my asset list

UPDATE :

I used [writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:) instead of UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum

```
alAssetLibrary.writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(image.CGImage, orientation: orientation) { (url, error) -> Void in
    alAssetLibrary.assetForURL(url, resultBlock: { (asset) -> Void in
        //code
    }, failureBlock: { (error) -> Void in
        //code
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum for saving a photo and I need to identify it in my asset list

If you need to identify the resulting asset, why are you using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`? It is a "stupid" function.

If you want to save an image as an asset into the library in such a way that you have access to that asset, you need to save it a "smart" way, such ALAssetsLibrary's `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum` - which has a completion handler that hands you the URL of the resulting asset.

Comment: Sorry, I just found it in the doc. Thank you!